# Cannot access Microsoft packages/apps website to create custom windows with ADK

Tags: windows, customization, http-error, adk

I'm trying to make my own custom windows using Windows ADK tools with latest packages (like Microsoft Store or Phone Link, etc...)

All the individual packages such as apps/misx are at http://tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/

but I cannot access the website, I get 403 error with this explanation:

```
Access to tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

Is there a workaround? why am I getting this error and is there a way to access the link?